# Hide global cursor

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to add some multi-touch gestures to Google Earth plugin, so I wrote a little c++ background program using the win32 API to catch the tactile driver input and make gestures with emulated mouse moves.

But now the mouse cursor is moving over the screen, so I want to hide it (I've already block the input using BlockInput function) while the user is touching the screen.

Is there a right way to do that ? I've saw the windows 8 CURSOR_SUPPRESSED response from GetCursorInfo, but no way to trigger that...

**EDIT :**
I found a dirty way, using SetSystemCursor to hide each cursors you need :

```
SetSystemCursor(hCursor, OCR_SIZENS);
```

and SystemParametersInfo to reset all cursors :

```
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETCURSORS, 0, NULL, 0);
```

I hope there is a better way to do...

Thanks !

Comment: Did you try recommendations from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760016/how-to-hide-and-disable-cursor-globally)?

Comment: Hiding the cursor from other application windows is generally a nasty thing to do, which is why there's no obvious way to do it.  If you capture the mouse (SetCapture), then the ShowCursor(FALSE) method would work.  I suspect you can't capture the mouse because you're expecting Earth to get the mouse input, but you didn't specify how you're emulating the mouse gestures.  SendInput?

Comment: Yes, I use SendInput to send mouse inputs to the plugins, emulating right or middle buttons down and mouse moves.

Answer (score 0):

i ran into this recently as dev of https://pandateemo.github.io/YoloMouse/ which changes your cursor in games. the only reliable way i could find without tangling with the target process or going into kernel land is to use a setwindowshook hack as follows:

```
DWORD       process_id;
HMODULE     dll = LoadLibraryA("User32.dll");
HOOKPROC    cbt = (HOOKPROC)((uint64_t)GetProcAddress(dll, "ShowCursor"));
HWND        hwnd = (HWND)FindWindow( NULL, "World of Warcraft" );
DWORD       hwnd_thread_id = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &process_id);
HHOOK       hproc = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, cbt, dll, hwnd_thread_id);
```

the reason its a hack is SetWindowsHookEx expects some function that looks like

```
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(
  _In_ int    code,
  _In_ WPARAM wParam,
  _In_ LPARAM lParam
);
```

found in target process. but instead youre giving it

```
int ShowCursor( BOOL bShow );
```

so when the hook fires it passes the **code**" value into the first parameter of whatever function you gave it, in this case **ShowCursor** and that value "always" happens to be 0 (FALSE).

go ahead and try above on some game or app, in this case its world of warcraft. push any keyboard key and cursor will disappear :)

you can use other hooks for this. to automate send whatever that hook expects to be triggered. in this case **SendInput** to emulate a key press. You can unhook after, unless app internally calls **ShowCursor(true)** later.